# Zapier Python Increment when variable is missing

Tags: zapier

I'm pulling a custom field from Klaviyo but sometimes it doesn't exist so there is no variable.

This works when the variable is present:

```
return {
  'new_total': int(input_data['original_total']) + 1
  }
```

But it errors out if the variable is blank.

What should the code look like in the zapier Python block to:

a) check if the variable exists as a number

b) set it to 0 if it doesn't

c) then increment it by 1 for the new_total?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Zapier's input_data variable, where you store all of the information you are working with in your code step, is a dictionary object. As such it has all of the methods of a Python dictionary available to it. The way in which you are currently accessing the values in your input_data dictionary returns an error when the provided key does not exist. As noted in Python's documentation:

> `d[key]`
>
> Return the item of d with key key. Raises a KeyError if key is not in the map

A more flexible means of accessing values in a dictionary when you are unsure of the presence of a specific key is to use `d.get(key)` the get method either returns `None` or a value you specify if the key cannot be found.

With your example you could modify it to be:

```
return {
  'new_total' : int(input_data.get('original_total', 0)) + 1
  }
```

In the above code if a key is not found a 0 will be returned and then incremented by 1. The 0 in the above code can be anything you specify, or you may also leave it blank to return `None` but this would lead to an error with your provided example.

You can read more about dictionaries [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping)